# Express the squared difference of given $n$ vectors in matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working with a linear algebra library so it would make my task easier if I can express what I want in matrix operations.

I have an $m$ by $n$ matrix.

$$
B= \begin{bmatrix}
| & | & \cdots & | \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & \cdots & b_{n} \\
| & | & \cdots & | \\
\end{bmatrix}    
$$

I want to produce an $n$ by $n$ matrix "D" where element $D_{i,j} = ||b_i - b_j||_2$. i.e., the sum of squared difference between two vectors. Essentially $D$ has the squared difference of all pairs of vectors.

How do I product this matrix through matrix operations? $C = B^TB$ will give me $C_{ij} = b_i^T b_j$ which is a bit different from what I want.

Comment: I imagine you mean $D_{i,j} = ||b_i - b_i||_2$. I think it will be difficult whereas I would be more optimistic for $D_{i,j} = ||b_i - b_i||^2_2$ (see Cayley-Menger determinant)

Comment: If you mean to vectorise the computation of $D$, you may calculate the Gram matrix $G=B^TB$ first. Then extract its diagonal elements to form a vector $v$. Now let $C=ve^T+ev^T-2G$ where $e$ is the all-one vector (you may want to calculate $C$ row by row using a for-loop rather than to compute the rank-one matrices $ve^T$ and $ev^T$ explicitly). Now $D$ is the entrywise square root of $C$.

Comment: @user1551 interesting and promising. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.